# Is there a way to specify an editor on a git command in a one-off style

Tags: git, editor, git-commit

Is run git using a one-off override to the git editor:

> $ git commit -m "my first commit" --editor="vim"

That will allow me to change the default editor without having to touch the GIT configuration.

Examples where this might be useful:

- When squashing lengthy histories or writing up messages for a feature commit.
- When performing automated edits to a commit, allowing a custom-script to manipulate the contents instead of a text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable just for one git execution:

```
GIT_EDITOR=nano git commit -a
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because I have a default editor configured globally in `~/.gitconfig`, and this command fails to override it.

Comment: I had to use `GIT_EDITOR` as explained in the answer to the duplicated question and in git documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var#Documentation/git-var.txt-GITEDITOR